# Near-future sci-fi short story with apologetic synthetic creatures cleaning up the environment and restraining humans from doing any more harm

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Trying to remember the name of near-future (~2070?) sci-fi short story I read about 6 months ago.

It features synthetic creatures which clean up pollution and prevent humans from harming the environment any more. The creatures non-violently restrain people - as I recall, one scene has them cleaning a beach, continually saying "sorry" or something like that. They are named after the sound they make.

Comment: Where are you likely to have read it? Online on a site like Reddit or in an anthology?

Comment: Online... maybe linked via Substack or Twitter?